# svg with javascript - axis labels

Tags: javascript, svg, styles

I am trying to label Y-axis of my graph using following code:

```
 svg1.append("text").attr("class", "y label")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.attr("y", 10)
.attr("dy", "-40")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.text("life expectancy (years)");
```

But when I try to change the 'y' value to 50, the label moves towards right, I am not able to understand why it is so. Moreover what is "dy" for, and why there is no "x" attribute.  :(

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you transform the default coordinate axes. i guess dy means dynamic-y and you can use x and dx.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TSpanElementDXAttribute

Comment: yea already read that link, but could not understand it well.